# Multiple iOS devices + centralized sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlite, database-connection

Can I share same sqlite database from 2 different iOS devices or update one from another?

Comment: I'm having 2 iPads with exactly the same list of people where information about these people being modified. I want the updated data to be available on another iPad without the use online database.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. You can sync the db over iCloud but there is a high chance that data will be overwritten.

I recommend writing some sort of syncing tool that can detect and merge changes originating on either device.

A Common method is to use a timestamp column and get all rows modified since the last sync, then update the other database.

Comment: Nice Idea with the timestamp. Thanx. Any ideas on syncing tool or the logic of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at OpenMobster's Sync Service. It supports multi-device sync operations with conflict management.

Besides this it supports the following sync modes:

- two-way
- one-way device
- one-way server
- bootup

You can run in complete offline mode and the changes will be auto-tracked and synchronized with the network returns. At this time sync happens with the Cloud and other devices that hold the same data that you are holding locally.

The project is located at: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

You can look at the following iOS sync tutorial to get an idea of how this thing works:
http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/iPhoneSyncApp